# Can I set a variable inside an array from a separate php file?

Tags: php, arrays, scope, global

Let's say I have a file effects.php with an array in it like

```
$techniqueDescriptions = array("damage" => "Deals ".$level." damage.");
```

And I have another file display.php that both gets the level and displays the attack like.

```
$level = $user->data["level"];
echo $techniqueDescriptions["damage"];
```

I tried the setup above and it gives "Deals  damage", even if I declare it global in both files. How can I get it to work, if it's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using level as a parameter.

effects.php:

```
function techniqueDescriptions($level) {
  return array("damage" => "Deals ".$level." damage.");
}
```

display.php:

```
require_once('effects.php')
$level = $user->data["level"];
echo techniqueDescriptions($level)["damage"];
```

Answer (score 4):

No. You're defining `$level` **AFTER** the array has been parsed/executed/constructed by PHP. PHP cannot "reach back in time" to retroactively insert a value for `$level` which didn't exist at the time you tried to insert `$level` into the array when it was being parsed.

You'd have to do something like

```
$level = 'foo';
include('array_gets_defined_here.php');
echo $techniqueDescriptions['damage'];
```

Doing it the other way around:

```
include('array_gets_defined_here.php');
$level = 'foo';
echo $techniqueDescriptions['damage'];
```

gets you into the time travel situation.